# Getting values from php array and outputting to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services

I'm new to php and I'm trying to create a webservice. I have a function to select a number of rows from a database which preforms correctly (it returns the 22 rows) but when I call that function from my index.php page and output to JSON I only get the first row being outputted.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

MySQL function:

```
    public function getStops()
    {
        //Perform query
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT station_name FROM station WHERE line =   2") or die(mysql_error());

        //Check result
        $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($numRows > 0)
        {
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Code in index.php calling getStops() function:

```
            //Check tag request
    if ($tag == "greenLineStations")
    {
        $greenStops = $db->getGreenLineStops();

        if ($greenStops != false)
        {
            //Get data and set success = 1
            $response["success"] = 1;
            foreach ($greenStops as $value)
            {
            $response["stops"]['name'] = $value;
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else
        {
            //Set error = 1 and out error message
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_message"] = "Error occured while retreiving stations";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
}
```

JSON dump:

```
    {"success":1,"error":0,"stops":[{"name":{"0":"St. Stephen's Green","station_name":"St. Stephen's Green"}},{"name":{"0":"Harcourt","station_name":"Harcourt"}},{"name":{"0":"Charlemont","station_name":"Charlemont"}},{"name":{"0":"Ranelagh","station_name":"Ranelagh"}},{"name":{"0":"Beechwood","station_name":"Beechwood"}},{"name":{"0":"Cowper","station_name":"Cowper"}},{"name":{"0":"Milltown","station_name":"Milltown"}},{"name":{"0":"Windy Arbour","station_name":"Windy Arbour"}},{"name":{"0":"Dundrum","station_name":"Dundrum"}},{"name":{"0":"Balally","station_name":"Balally"}},{"name":{"0":"Kilmacud","station_name":"Kilmacud"}},{"name":{"0":"Stillorgan","station_name":"Stillorgan"}},{"name":{"0":"Sandyford","station_name":"Sandyford"}},{"name":{"0":"Central Park","station_name":"Central Park"}},{"name":{"0":"Glencairn","station_name":"Glencairn"}},{"name":{"0":"The Gallops","station_name":"The Gallops"}},{"name":{"0":"Leopardstown Valley","station_name":"Leopardstown Valley"}},{"name":{"0":"Ballyogan Wood","station_name":"Ballyogan Wood"}},{"name":{"0":"Carrickmines","station_name":"Carrickmines"}},{"name":{"0":"Laughanstown","station_name":"Laughanstown"}},{"name":{"0":"Cherrywood","station_name":"Cherrywood"}},{"name":{"0":"Brides Glen","station_name":"Brides Glen"}}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   if($numRows > 0)
   {
      $return = array();
      while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $return[] = $array;
      }
      return $return;
   }
```

and :

```
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response['stops'] = array();
        foreach ($greenStops as $value){
            $response["stops"][]['name'] = $value[0];
        }
```

Comment: This helps a lot thankyou but it gives me the data twice. It outputs the root node and a secondary node for each station

Comment: Sure, I added it above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your foreach loop in the index.php is just overwriting the same index over and over again. Depending on how you want the output to be structured I would suggest changing the line 12 to:

```
$response["stops"][]['name'] = $value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this combined with Loic's answer gets me a lot further but it outputs the data twice, I seem to be getting the root node and a secondary node outputted each time for each row